# Call class method with symbol input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, hash, class-method

I have a class method:

```
class CountryCodes
  def self.country_codes
    { AF: "Afghanistan",
    AL: "Albania",
    ... }
  end
end
```

I have a rake task that creates a City, with a country_code like "AF". I would like it to replace "AF" with "Afghanistan" by calling the class method and referencing the key-value pair.

The current functionality which sets the country_code to be like "AF" is:

```
city = City.create do |c|
   c.name = row[:name] 
   c.country_code = row[:country_code] # sets country_code to be like "AF"
end
```

I can manually retrieve "Afghanistan" by calling `puts CountryCodes.country_codes[:AF]`. By combining these tactics, I (incorrectly) thought I could:

```
city = City.create do |c|
   c.name = row[:name] 
   c.country_code = CountryCodes.country_code[:row[:country_code]] #obviously, this failed
end
```

The failure that occurs when I run this is:

> rake aborted!
>   TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

How can I correctly call the `CountryCodes.country_code` class method with a dynamic input of `row[:country_code]`?

Comment: How exactly did it fail? It looks like you're writing `:row[:country_code]`, which will fail because the symbol `:row` is not the variable `row` that you want.

Comment: I've added the error that occurs to the question. How can I fix the error that you are referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `CountryCodes.country_code` has a hash of symbols, you need to call a symbol when referencing it. For example: `country_code["AF"]` is NOT the same as `country_code[:AF]`.

To correct this, convert your string `row[:country_code]` to a symbol using Ruby's `to_sym`:

```
city = City.create do |c|
   c.name = row[:name] 
   c.country_code = CountryCodes.country_code[row[:country_code].to_sym]  # < .to_sym
end
```

Since I cannot see your schema, my answer is also assuming that `country_code` is a `String` in your `City` model (not an integer.)

Comment: It's type `text`! Hope that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Text is also fine. As long as it's not expecting an integer. Let me know if this is working for you, or if you get another error.

Answer (score 0):

serious answer:

use the country_code Gem!
https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select
https://github.com/hexorx/countries
https://github.com/alexrabarts/iso_country_codes

I18n ready and whatever

Comment: Have you used any of these before?